# how to make a new figure in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, button, user-interface, figure, toolbox

i hope you all can help me.

How to make new figure from push button or anything toolbox in gui matlab.
in my case, when i click/push button that will open new figure..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to place the command

```
newFigH = figure();
```

in the callback function of the event you want to act upon. That is, if you want the figure to open when you push a button, put `figure()` in the push button callback function.